# angular 12 issue in ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have upgraded my solution from Angular 11 to 12 . Getting issue on `ng build` production in Angular 12.

Issue:

> styles.9d2c30b5b89587c78732.css - Error:
> styles.9d2c30b5b89587c78732.css from Css Minimizer TypeError: Cannot
> set property 'type' of undefined
> at D:\Angular\styles.9d2c30b5b89587c78732.css:6058:5
> at D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss-ordered-values\dist\lib\getValue.js:22:38
> at Array.reduce ()
> at getValue (D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss-ordered-values\dist\lib\getValue.js:12:19)
> at normalizeBoxShadow (D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss-ordered-values\dist\rules\boxShadow.js:58:32)
> at D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss-ordered-values\dist\index.js:144:28
> at D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:72:18
> at D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:55:18
> at Rule.each (D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:41:16)
> at Rule.walk (D:\Angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:52:17

Comment: is it building fine with angular 11?

Comment: yes. it is working fine with angular 11

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 possible situation in your case:

1. You're defining a property to an undefined object,. You have to initialize your object before setting properties.

`$scope.message = {};`

`$scope.message.test = 'xyz';`

2. Seems like there is an issue with your node_modules. Try these:

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Run this command:
   `npm cache clean --force`
3. Reinstall specific Angular version.
4. Now run the `ng serve` or `npm start` command.